# Replace every third line in a text file with content from another text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, readline

Trying to replace every third line with the actual subtitles.

Background: I'm making subtitles from music videos and movies with the help of Videosubfinder and an ocr api.

emptySub.srt (automatically created with Videosubfinder)

```
1
00:00:10,076 --> 00:00:15,080
sub duration: 5,004

2
00:00:57,891 --> 00:01:01,694
sub duration: 3,803
```

subtitle.txt looks like this (used an ocr api and looped through images, you don't need to see the code)

```
I bought some eggs.
He bought some spam.
```

Code

```
with open("empty.srt", "a") as file:
    for line in file:
        # TODO
```

Expected output

```
1
00:00:10,076 --> 00:00:15,080
I bought some eggs.

2
00:00:57,891 --> 00:01:01,694
He bought some spam.
```

I am so stuck. How to replace with my subtitles? Maybe I should use regex I don't know.

EDIT: I finally solved it by myself

Comment: Expected output? I didn't get which 3rd line you are talking about

Comment: this line sub duration: 5,004. Every line that says sub duration. Oh only the first time it's the third line my mistake. Then everytime after it seems to be the fourth line.

Comment: Your Python "attempt" doesn't demonstrate any actual effort; this is simply a "gimme code" question. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I'm only a beginner.

Comment: You can still try to articulate a question around an actual coding problem. How do I read from multiple files? How do I keep track of the line number? How do I select every third one of something? You have done nothing to address any of these questions, and explaining all of them properly will be a large task. Hence, too broad. Also, you could at least show us that you have tried to search for information before asking here.

Comment: Please add your own solution as an answer and not as an edit to the question. I'm voting to reopen the question so that you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subList = []
with open("subtitle.txt", "r") as subFile:
    for subLine in subFile:
        subList.append(subLine.rstrip())

print(subList)

i = 0
with open("emptySub.srt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('s'):
            line = line.replace(line, subList[i]+'\n')
            i = i + 1
        with open('newFile.srt','a') as resFile:
            resFile.write(line)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call `with open('newFile.srt','a') as resFile:` at every tick of the `for` loop (although python/the OS might well optimize this); you could move that line so that both `with open` calls are next to each other and you only open each file once.

Answer (score 0):

You want some variant of:

```
subtitleLines = open('subtitle.txt', 'r')

# Creates a list of lines
srtLines = open('srtfile.srt', 'r').readlines()

for (i, line) in enumerate(subtitleLines):
  srtLines[3*i + 2] = line

# emit srtLines
```

This will perform well for files in the KB to ~MBish range, but if the file is huge, you will instead want to advance the srt `file` faster than the subtitle `file`. How do you advance an open file? By calling `next()`:

```
# after reading in subtitle.txt into subtitleFile:
for line in subtitleFile:
  for i in range(2):
    # Your "next" line will have a newline, so suppress print()'s
    # default newline.
    print(srtFile.next(), end="")
  # advance without printing
  srtFile.next()
  print line
```

You will want to catch `StopIteration` and decide what to do once the SRT file "runs out" - that is up to you whether you want to validate.

Note, however, that from your example, it looks like every 4th line starting from the 3rd that is a subtitle line (there is a blank line between the srt blocks).

Comment: I've never used enumerate before

Comment: enumerate takes an "iterable" object (basically an object that you can go through in some sequential order, and produces both the current count of items emitted plus the item emitted: (0, line0), (1, line1), (2, line2), ... which is super useful if you need both the value and the index (as you might have using a standard for loop in another language).

Comment: subtitleFile is not defined

Comment: yes, subtitleFile is a file handle obtained by calling open('path/to/subtitle.txt', 'r'). I didn't think to write that part out, since it looks like you are familiar with opening files. I've added a comment to my code

Comment: srtFile has no attribue 'next'